# RevMob not initializing properly [iOS Xcode]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, revmob

I'm creating an iOS application that uses mainly iAds, but since their fill rate is so low I wanted to add another revenue source to use when the iAds do not load. I've decided to use RevMob since I've used them for another app of mine and they have been pretty good.

When I run the app, here's what I get:

```
2014-02-11 18:53:50.364 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
2014-02-11 18:53:50.694 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] Initializating Banner.
2014-02-11 18:53:50.695 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] Requesting banner data.
2014-02-11 18:53:51.176 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] Device requirements not met (422).
2014-02-11 18:53:51.177 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] Error on banner: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Device requirements not met (422). error -1.)
2014-02-11 18:53:51.179 Colors[5629:60b] Ad error: Error Domain=Device requirements not met (422). Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Device requirements not met (422). error -1.)"
2014-02-11 18:53:51.209 Colors[5629:60b] [RevMob] App can't be registered in RevMob servers
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [RevMobAds startSessionWithAppID:@"*(I've tried deleting and re-adding the app in RevMob and getting a new id to no avail)"];
//    [RevMobAds session].parallaxMode = RevMobParallaxModeOff;
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:1];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [[RevMobAds session] hideBanner];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [banner setAlpha:0];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self loadRevMobAd];
}

-(void)loadRevMobAd {
    RevMobBannerView *banner = [[RevMobAds session] bannerView];
    banner.delegate = self;

    [banner loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
        if (adBanner) {
            [banner setFrame:adBanner.frame];
            NSLog(@"Loaded adBanner");
        } else {
            [banner setFrame:iPadAdBanner.frame];
            NSLog(@"Loaded iPadAdBanner");
        }
        [self.view addSubview:banner];
        NSLog(@"Ad loaded");
    } andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Ad error: %@",error);
    } onClickHandler:^(RevMobBannerView *banner) {
        NSLog(@"Ad clicked");
    }];
}
```

I've used RevMob before and don't remember ever having this much trouble. When I'm running this app on Xcode I'm building it on my iPhone 5s (7.0.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct as i'm also receiving this issue now. I've just upgraded my revmob sdk to the latest and now its not working on ios 7 whereas ios 6 works pretty well. It seems the problem coming from latest revmob sdk as i was able to see ads on older sdks yesterday.

Comment: I have RevMob working.  Start the session in your app delegate.  Then in the view controller that first shows ads, have a dispatch after of 2 or so seconds and that will allow the session to start.